# Discord.py bot not reacting with custom emoji

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a Discord.py bot, and I am trying to get it to react to one specific person, with a custom emoji. The bot is in the server with the emoji, but I get this error: `discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji`
i am new to Discord.py btw lol.

here is my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author.id == 514605665306673172:
await message.add_reaction('<:android:332598085782077451>')
```

The code works otherwise, if I were to use a default Discord Emoji. Any help would be greatly appreciated

(Python 3.8.2)

Comment: that's weird, It works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting a `discord.Emoji` object, here's how

```py
emoji = bot.get_emoji(332598085782077451)
await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Also make sure to enable default intents and `intents.members`

Comment: i tried that already, i get the same error :(
but where would i put the intents.members

Comment: [here's](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents) an introduction to privileged intents, take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the correct emoji name and id? If you aren't sure you can get it by using `/:emoji_name:` (go to the server, type the emoji, put a / in front of it. You'll see the the emoji going back to its :name: form with the / in front of it.) And sending that. With custom emojis discord will send the name:id of the emoji. (Normal emojis will return the unicode character).